# How will Spring handle two XML config files with the same name?

Tags: java, spring

I have a project A which dependent on B.jar and C.jar. They both have a resource file named `spring-datasource.xml` in classpath. When project A import `spring-datasouce.xml` , which one will be chosed? How does A make the decision?

Answer (score 0):

If these two files contain different bean definitions then it will simply create all the bean definitions in both of these files. The fact that the files have the same name is irrelevant.

If the two files define beans with the same **name** then Spring will override the earlier definition with the later definition. For example: if `B.jar::spring-datasource.xml` and `C.jar::spring-datasource.xml` both contains a bean named `dataSource` then ...

- If Spring encounters `B.jar::spring-datasource.xml` first it will create the `dataSource` bean as per the definition in that file and then when it encounters `C.jar::spring-datasource.xml` it will override the `dataSource` bean with the definition in `C.jar::spring-datasource.xml` bean.3
- If Spring encounters `C.jar::spring-datasource.xml` first then the reverse will happen.

This term: "encounters first" refers to the way in which Spring discovers XML configuration files i.e. the ordering of the files as they are loaded into the Spring context. Typically, this will be controlled by the order of `B.jar` and `C.jar` in your runtime classpath.

If you are concerned about this i.e. if you need to be certain about the order in which your beans are declared then either:

- Do not have multiple definitions of the **same** bean name
- Ensure that the order of `B.jar` and `C.jar` in your classpath delivers these XML files to the Spring context in your preferred order

This isn't really recommended; it's brittle and error prone.

FWIW using Java config with the `@Primary` annotation or using Spring Profiles to control what Spring config is loaded would both offer more control over this situation.